# Unable to properly formulate XPath syntax to search in complexe xml file

Tags: xml, xpath

I am having problem in formulating correctly my XPath to research in an XML file  I am Visual Basic 2015 with the 4.0 net framework and it's in an excel template

Here is part of the xml file

```
      <Data ss:Type="String">1000102043</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String"></Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="Number">1.0</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">Lot / Fourre-tout</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Currency">
      <Data ss:Type="Number">320,38</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Currency">
      <Data ss:Type="Number">320,38</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">CAD</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="Number">1.0</Data>
```

I need to only get the line where there is a "Number" field in my search where ss:Type="Number"

At this point I can only get all the "Data" field with this

```
xmlNodePrice = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Data")
```

So this works but I need only the number lines

I have tried this

```
xmlNodePrice = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("//Data(@Type='Number')")
```

and also this

```
xmlNodePrice = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("//Data[@Type='Number''")
```

still no go

Comment: `GetElementsByTagName()` sounds like it takes a tag name (an element name), not a full XPath expression. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx on how to select nodes using an XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> xmlNodePrice = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("//Data[@Type='Number''")
> ```

This calls `GetElementsByTagName()` and does as its name suggests: it takes a tag name and selects those elements that match the tag name.

If you want to use XPath, you can use the [`SelectNodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`SelectSingleNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which take a whole XPath, not just a tag name as their first argument. The overloads (with a second argument) can take a namespace manager. See the [link from LarsH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx) and the two links above for more info and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer it guided me in the right direction but I had a lot of work to do to figure the rest out.

Here is my final code WORKING

```
    Public strPathFile As String
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim xmlNode As XmlNodeList
    Dim nsMgr As XmlNamespaceManager
    Dim selectedNodes As XmlNodeList

    xmlDoc.Load(strPathFile)

    nsMgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office")
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel")
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("html", "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40")
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")

    selectedNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row/ss:Cell/ss:Data[@ss:Type=""Number""]", nsMgr)
    For Each selectedNode As XmlNode In selectedNodes
        'Do whatever
        End If
    Next
```

And here is the xml file

```
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">each / par pi&#232;ce</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Currency">
      <Data ss:Type="Number">0,51</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="Currency">
      <Data ss:Type="Number">1,02</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="String">CAD</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Data ss:Type="Number">0.0</Data>
```